# Refreshig NHibernate object

Tags: c#, validation, nhibernate, repository, automapper

I am working on existing project in which by convention domain models are created and mapped in controller actions. For example ItemController has method UpdateItem which accepts UpdateItemViewModel. The model has only few properties comparing to the domain model which has many of them. Now, the convention is to use AutoMapper for mapping properties, and it looks more or less like this

```
public JsonResult UpdateItemForSale(UpdateItemViewModel itemViewModel) 
{
   if(!ModelState.IsValid)
       //some response is returned
   var itemFromRepo = _itemRepository.FindItemById(itemViewModel.Id);
   var updatedItem = Mapper.Map<UpdateItemViewModel, Item>(itemViewMode, itemFromRepo);

   var validationResult = _itemService.Validate(updatedItem);
   // rest of the code basing on validation result
}
```

the validate has to check method looks like this:

```
public ValidationResults GetValidationResults(Item item)
{
    ///some initial code
    var itemInRepo = ItemRepository.Find(item.Id);
    //read the text below
}
```

here i want to check if the changes conform to some business rules but... it turns out that item object and itemInRepo object is the same object (ReferenceEquals returns true). It is probably because NHibernate does not look to the database if the object was loaded into the memory. Therefore I have no access to the original database entity and cannot perform the necessary checks. Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem according to the good practises?

I know this Refresh method, and it surely works. I am rather asking about a "good-practice" way to handle such a problem. In my GetValidationResults method itemInRepo and item is the same object. If i refresh itemInRepo, I will also change item. I though about creating a fresh instance of item (which calls for some factory, since Item is an abstract class), then copying the properties from item to this fresh copy (which will probably won't be easy due to some overriden properties in child classes), then I would refresh the itemInRepo using Refresh method, and then I could validate them. After validation passes I could copy properties from my fresh copy to itemInRepo and save them. This approach seems very, very cumbersome to me and I don't know if it's possible at all using Automapper (due to the virtual/overriden properties). Someone has any better idea? Please, don't point out flaws in the design - for example: "you should pass some dto object to the GetValidationResults method instead of entity model object". I know this - but the code is as it is and I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Refresh()` and `Lock()` methods on the `ISession`. You're always going to face the risk of stale data though.

Comment: Thank you, but please read my edited question - I've put some additional info.

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to compare the view model's values against the entity's currently persisted values?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For example one of the properties can be changed only if one of the other properties has particular value - this is an example of validation that I need to perform. But both variable item, and itemInRepo point to the same object which has updated properties.